# date -d 'previous Monday" to display the preceding Monday

Tags: bash

With `date -d` could display the future or next date

```
$ date -d "next mon"
Mon May 13 00:00:00 CST 2019

$ date -d "mon"
Mon May 13 00:00:00 CST 2019
```

Unfortunately, it failed to display the previous weekday

```
$ date -d "previous Monday"
date: invalid date ‘previous Monday’
```

How could display the previous weekday in a string-format?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `last` instead of `previous`:

```
$ date -d "last Monday"
Mon May  6 00:00:00 BST 2019
```

This is documented in `info date`, and the specific mention of `last` is in the ["29.6 Day of week items"](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Day-of-week-items.html#Day-of-week-items) section (thanks to @Jos and @hobbs for finding it):

> A number may precede a day of the week item to move forward supplementary weeks. It is best used in expression like ‘third monday’. In this context, ‘last day’ or ‘next day’ is also acceptable; they move one week before or after the day that day by itself would represent.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93444/discussion-on-answer-by-terdon-date-d-previous-monday-to-display-the-precedin).